# Getting error 'IntelliTrace code failed (0x80131509)' when trying to debug Visual Studio 2019 solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, intellitrace

I am getting this issue when I try to debug an application that I tried to convert to SDK style. More information below. I am posting this in the hopes that someone can post a solution here. When I click ok to this error, the solution just disappears from VS like I had opened it without any solution at all.

> IntelliTrace code failed (0x80131509) 
> Managed (.NET 4.x) code succeeded.

I have looked at other SO and forum posts about this issue, and the resolutions seem to be that they rebuilt their machine. Which is not really an option for me at the moment. I can try to re-install Visual Studio, which I might do soon.

#### How I came to be in this situation:

I tried to use [Try-Convert](https://github.com/dotnet/try-convert) to convert an existing .NET application to SDK style format. I have done this with other projects in the past with success. All I have to do is manually edit the TargetFramework aftewards to point to net472 or the desired version. In this case the conversion went very badly as this is an older code project with some pretty customized project files. As it went badly I decided to try to revert the projects to the old project format, and that is when this occurred.

#### Things I have tried:

- Cleaning out the entire source folder, and re-getting latest
- Running devenv /setup
- Cleaning out both the %temp%, and asp.net temporary files directory.
- Rebooting
- All the options listed here by Del [Developer Community Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/vs-gives-error-intellitrace-code-failed-0x80131509/1464763) (Except repair which I am about to attempt)
- Turning off IntelliTrace

Comment: OK, the VS Repair worked. I followed the instructions here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019